# how to get current thread(worker) in rust rocket

Tags: rust

Now I am using rust rocket `rocket = { version = "0.5.0-rc.1", features = ["json"] }` as a web server, I am facing a problem when the request quickly, some request may turn to time out, my server side code look like this:

```
#[post("/v1",data = "<record>")]
pub fn word_search(record: Json<WordSearchRequest>, login_user_info: LoginUserInfo) -> content::Json<String> {
    // some logic to fetch data from database
}
```

I was wonder why the requst turned to time out, so I want to print the server side thread and handle request time. is it possible to get current thread id in rust rocket? I am seriously doubt the server only have one thread.

Answer (score 0):

I finnally found the server only have one worker from the log ouput, then I add more workers in the `Rocket.toml` config file fix the timeout problem.

```
[release]
workers = 12
log_level = "normal"
keep_alive = 5
port = 8000
```